# Doubt on the proof of the Jordan-Hölder theorem for groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation

I've been reading the proof of the Jordan-Hölder theorem on the book Abstract Algebra, Theory and Applications by Thomas W. Judson [Chapter 13, Theorem 13.18](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Abstract_and_Geometric_Algebra/Abstract_Algebra%3A_Theory_and_Applications_(Judson)/13%3A_The_Structure_of_Groups/13.02%3A_Solvable_Groups)

> Any two composition series of G are isomorphic

The proof uses strong induction on n, where n is the length of a composition series of G (it is not explicitely stated whether it's the minimal composition series or not). We then consider two arbitrary composition series for G, one of  lenght n {$H_i$} and other of lenght k {$K_j$}. Out of this two series we create two equivalent composition series, one for {$H_i$}, and other for {$K_j$}.
$$G = H_n ⊃ H_{n−1} ⊃ H_{n−1} ∩ K_{m−1} ⊃ · · · ⊃ H_0 ∩ K_{m−1} =\{e\} $$
$$G = K_m ⊃ K_{n−1} ⊃ K_{m−1} ∩ H_{n−1} ⊃ · · · ⊃ K_0 ∩ H_{n−1} =\{e\} $$
Respectively (Possible because of the second isomorphism theorem). Finally we show that the two created series are equivalent to each other.

But I don't get the last part of the proof.
[Part of the proof in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82N2f.png) Why does $K_{m−1}/(K_{m-1} ∩ H_{n−1}) \cong G/H_{n−1}$ imply that the two created series are equivalent? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Symmetrically, we also have $H_{n-1} / (K_{m-1} \cap H_{n-1}) \cong H_{n-1} K_{m-1} / K_{m-1} = G / K_{m-1}$. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Please try to make your questions self-contained.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I see, I think I get it. What was proven was the base case, and then we would proceed by induction to prove that indeed the two series are isomorphic?